# Python writing to Excel file: writerow() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, error-handling, web-scraping

I have this script:

```
    import requests
    from requests import get
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv
    import pandas as pd

    f = open('olanda.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    url = ('https://www......')
    response = get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    type(soup)

    table = soup.find('table', id='tablepress-94').text.strip()

    print(table)

    writer.writerow(table.split(), delimiter = ',')

    f.close()
```

When it writes to a CSV file it writes everything in a single cell like that:

Sno.,CompanyLocation,1KarifyNetherlands,2Umenz,Benelux,BVNetherlands,3TovertafelNetherlands,4Behandeling,BegrepenNetherlands,5MEXTRANetherlands,6Sleep.aiNetherlands,7OWiseNetherlands,8Healthy,WorkersNetherlands,9&thijs,|,thuis,in,jouw,situatieNetherlands,10HerculesNetherlands, etc.

I wanted to have the output in a single column and each value (separated by comma) in a single row.

I tried to use delimiter = ',' but I got:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.

Screesnhot of table:
[image: table]

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see doc of [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

`delimiter` param is used when instantiating the `writer`, not on `writerow` method.

Furthermore from what I understand, your approach is wrong.
For example you want to scrape the html table and store it as csv file.

But what you do is get the text from table

```py
table = soup.find('table', id='tablepress-94').text.strip()
```

which is a **concatenated string of all columns with no structure and try to split by nothing**, which is wrong

while you should be getting a `dict` of table values, eg using:

```py
table = soup.find('table', id='tablepress-94')
# assuming table has a
# <thead><tr><td>Column 1</td>..<td>Column n</td></tr></thead>
# section with column headers, else adjust accordingly
column_headers = [td.get_text() for td in table.find('thead').find('tr').find_all('th')]
print(column_headers)
data = {}
row_index = 0
for row in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
    row_index += 1
    column_index = 0
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    for td in columns:
        if column_index >= len(column_headers):
            column_headers.append('Column_'+str(column_index+1))
        if column_headers[column_index] not in data:
            data[column_headers[column_index]] = []
        data[column_headers[column_index]].append(td.get_text())
        column_index += 1

print(data)
# now output your scarped table data, data into csv properly
writer.writerow(column_headers) # print headers

# print each row of data
for row in range(row_index):
    writer.writerow([data[column][row] for column in column_headers])
```

Comment: True, thanks I didn't notice it. However, it doesn't work with .split() because I get  writer.writerow(table.split())

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable    but I need .split() because I get written html code and not text.

Comment: @Steven your approach as far as I see is wrong, see updated answer and hope it helps. If it helps you should consider acceptng it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. With a simple print(data) I actually get what I want, but when it comes to print it doesn't work. So I tried your code and I get  if column_headers[column_index] not in data: data[column_headers[column_index]] = []

IndexError: list index out of range    I was trying to understand why it is out of range but so far I haven't find it out.

Comment: @Steven, please `print(column_headers)` to make sure they are extracted correctcly or are indeed there and let me know. Possibly you have to adjust the code the correctly extract the table headers if you know the table structure and have some understandfing of html and soup

Comment: I printed column_headers but it returned the same error. I uploaded the html code in the question. I wanted to extract the company names, eg Karify, and possibly the corresponded url. I don't know why the range is related to the tag I want to extract.

Comment: @Steven you should add the screenshot too your question, not in answer. Anyway the screenshot does not show the table headers..please add to **your question** a screesnhot with the table headers as well

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Should be fine now, thanks.

Comment: @Steven ok updated answer, but you could have figured this out yourself. Cheers!

Comment: @Steven, if the answer solved the problem you should consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm going to, thanks! Just one more thing if you can, do you know why each row is written like that: 1,Karify,Netherlands   all in one cell, with comma separating words?

Comment: @Steven, comma is the csv delimiter you set, or if not set then the default delimiter. You can change the delimiter when instantiating the writer see the doc i linked for further details. Cheers!

Comment: Got it, thanks again!